# scalebox not acting as expected within titlesec formatting

Tags: titlesec

In the following MWE, the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` block gives a specific format to the title/author of the article. My hope is to match that formatting with the section/subsection titles using `titlesec`. However, I can't find a way to make the font size of the section\subsection titles match that of their title/author complement. My attempts at using `\scalebox` just result in a section/subsection title that is simply normal size.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{-\topskip}
  \begingroup\centering
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \hrule height \z@
    {\begin{flushleft} \LARGE \scalebox{3}{\textsc{\textbf{\@title}}} \par \end{flushleft}}%
    \vskip -2em 
    {\color{black} \hfill \large \scalebox{3}{\textsc{\textbf{\@author}}} \par }%
  \par\endgroup
  \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\LARGE \bfseries \scshape}{}{0em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\vskip -2em \hfill \large \scshape \bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Title}

\subsection{Author}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Easiest solution would be to not use `\scalebox` but a scalable font and `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont` instead.

Comment: Or even better, stick with the provided sizes  `\Huge` and the like, and don't use anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not at all sure what you are trying to do ... or rather why you are trying to do it this way.

The problem is simple: your redefinition of `\@maketitle` is placing `\LARGE` and `\large` size text (i.e., for `10pt` class option, 17.28pt and 12pt text) inside a `\scalebox` which is scaling it up by 3, so that it becomes just under 52pt and 36pt text respectively. But your titlesec definitions don't (and can't easily be made to because of how it works).

As Skillmon pointed out in the comments, the sensible way to deal with scaling fonts is to use font scaling directly, and get rid of the scale box completely.

However, you're not quite home and dry. If you want scalable fonts above ordinary sizes, you will need something to give you suitable large fonts in computer modern. (This was probably the reason for the scalebox in your code, which is a way round that, but which I'm guessing you inherited.) Here there's a whole heap of possibilities: `lmodern`, `fix-cm` or just compile with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

In fact, there's another oddity here: your code looks for small caps, but regular Computer Modern doesn't have bold small caps. If you actually **want** them you will need, I think, `fix-cm` with `fontenc`. So that's what I've demonstrated.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% NB Before documentclass
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% ALTERNATIVE POSSIBILITIES TO FIX-CM AND T1: \usepackage{lmodern}
% or use XeTeX or LuaTeX to compile (but bold small caps have
% wrinkles of their own
% \usepackage{tikz} not needed

\newcommand\myLARGE{\fontsize{51.84pt}{64pt}}
\newcommand\mylarge{\fontsize{36pt}{42pt}}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{-\topskip}
  \begingroup\centering
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \hrule height \z@
    {\begin{flushleft} \myLARGE\scshape\bfseries\@title\par \end{flushleft}}%
    \vskip -2em 
    {\hfill \mylarge\scshape\bfseries\@author\par}%
  \par\endgroup
  \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\myLARGE\scshape\bfseries}{}{0em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\vskip -2em \hfill\mylarge\scshape\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Title}

\subsection{Author}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing identical title and section titles]

Comment: I'm using the Alegreya package, which comes with small caps; I erroneously removed that for the MWE. Terrific solution, thank you!